# how to insert page title in css only with no access to HTML code

Tags: css

I'm working currently in editing css files of a LMS theme and I need to change the page title by inserting it in css files.
I want to know the css code that should be written in this case.

Answer (score 3):

CSS is for formatting. HTML is for data. This can't and shouldn't be done.

Comment: This is correct but you could use the `content` property to set data for an page element.

Answer (score 1):

CSS is for telling a web browser how to display data while HTML is to tell the web browser what to display.

Therefor this can not be done in CSS